# Screen randomly switches to console

Tags: 13.04, command-line, display, suspend, tty

I have the following problem with Ubuntu 13.04: GUI randomly switches to console mode. If I suspend and wake up, it is in GUI again.

A related issue is when I switch to a different terminal (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) and then switch back to tty7 (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>) - I see the same console I mentioned before (looks like a system log).

I tried all <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>FN</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>FN</kbd>, but it does not help. The only thing that helps is suspending (i.e. closing the lid) and waking up.

Comment: It may be your display manager which is causing this. Another possible issue may your graphics driver. So first I want you to try the suggestion that I'm posting in my answer. Give it a try: if it doesn't work then we'll proceed further.

Comment: Could you take a photo when this happens? Also, upload the content of the `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` file next time this happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try to reconfigure lightdm, it may fix your issue**

- Open terminal(<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and execute following command:

  ```
  sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
  ```
- Then chose `lightdm` from the list.
- Restart your system:

  ```
  sudo reboot now
  ```

It may fix your issue. If doesn't fix then follow *2nd Method*.

**Method 2:**

Installing a new display manager can fix your problem. Steps to install **GDM**(a display manager much like *lightdm*):

- Open terminal(<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and execute following commands:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install gdm
  sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
  ```

  then chose `gdm` from the list. And restart your system:

  ```
  sudo reboot now
  ```

Hope these methods solve your issue. Reply if something goes wrong..

Comment: So far the first method seems to have solved the problem. I'll see if it survives a couple of restarts and accept the solution. Thanks! By the way, is this a known issue, is it reported to lightdm or ubuntu developers?

Comment: Sounds good!! :) It would be `lightdm` because same issue arrived for me.. I removed `lighdm` and installed `gdm`, till then I've never faced such issue.. ;)